# Safe Datalog rules for the query

Tags: database-design

The 3 relations ( edge(X,Y), Red(X,y), Blue(X,Y) ) are considered a graph whose relations can be colored red/blue. Could you please guide me to:

a) Find the pairs of nodes X and Y where there is a path (a sequence of linked edges) from X to Y ? According to what I understand I think the answer should be path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z) , edge(Z,Y). Is it correct?

b) Find the pairs of nodes X and Y where there is path (a sequence of linked edges) of even length from X to Y with alternating red and blue colors. How can I modify the answer to first part to get the answer for 2nd part?

Comment: I don't see how this is a dba question.   Maybe try programmers.se